# How to Show only Lowest Price Duplicate Product in Catalog listing..?

Tags: category, product-list

I am duplicating the product programmatically by keeping the same name and images but with different Prices and sku and displaying it in the same Category.
When I go to Product Listing page, all the duplicated products and the Parent product are displayed but with different price and sku.
I want to filter the catalog listing such that only the product with lowest price(among the duplicate products including their parent product) should be displayed.

Comment: Perhaps a grouped product would be better suited to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way of doing this.
Once the product is duplicated, the clone becomes a separate product with no reference to the original product. It's just like adding a different product manually.

What you can do is to change the visibility of the products you don't want to appear in the list to `Not visible individually` or set the status to disabled

There is no out of the box of doing it via code.